# How to use @PathParam?

Tags: json, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I am following simple steps of tutorial and till now I cant figure out why it displays error.

I am trying to return simple JSON using a simple JAX-RS application.
The following is my code and `web.xml` settings:

```
package ws;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/employee/{empno}")
public class EmployeeResource {

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    public EmployeeResource() {
    }

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String getJson( @PathParam("empno") int empno) {
      switch(empno) {
          case 1 :
              return "{'name':'George Koch', 'age':58}";
          case 2:
              return "{'name':'Peter Norton', 'age':50}";
          default:
              return "{'name':'unknown', 'age':-1}";
      }
    }

    @PUT
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public void putJson(String content) {
    }
}
```

`web.xml` is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
           http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>ws</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
      <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
  </web-app>
```

And then I use address:

```
localhost:8084/restdemo/resources/employee/empno=1
```

but it shows 404 error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call

```
localhost:8084/restdemo/resources/employee/1
```

A `@PathParam` is not a `@QueryParam`. Its name is derived from its position in the query path, not by a give name like `empno=1`. Since your `@Path` is

```
@Path("/employee/{empno}")
```

the element of your URL path that is at the position of `{empno}` is automatically assigned to your `@PathParam` `empno`.

**Edit:**

If you want to call a URL like

```
localhost:8084/restdemo/resources/employee?empno=1
```

you must use

```
@Path("/employee")
public String getJson(@QueryParam("empno") int empno)
```

Note the `?` that is the border between the URL path left of it and the query on the right of it.

**Hint:**

Your JSON is not valid. You must use double quotes `"` instead of single quotes `'`:

```
return "{\"name\":\"George Koch\", \"age\":58}";
```